# cx_Oracle build/install error RHEL 7

Tags: python, rhel, cx-oracle

I have recently been working on a project which hosts a web portal on cherrypy and one of the features is that it will take all user submissions from many different forms and then send those values back to an oracle DB. I have been able to fairly easily setup my testing environment both locally on my windows laptop and a RHEL development box. The thing is, at those locations I have had root/admin access.

But currently as I move to push this out to a non-development box it has required getting unix admins involved to actually do the necessary installs and such.

The first error that came up was the missing Python.h file and the build of the cx_Oracle module would fail whether it was done via pip or by building the source code with `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install`. I quickly recognized this as that we did not have the necessary python-devel package installed, once the admin ran the `yum install python-devel.x86_64` command the necessary files were in place to make it at least a bit farther in the install process.

After that was completed I tried to once again build via pip and with the source code but had a similar error about an oci.h file being missing. I then noticed my user did not have the proper LD_LIBRARY_PATH or ORACLE_HOME paths set, so I set them to as seen in the echos below

```
-bash-4.2$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib:/usr/include/oracle/12.2/client64/
-bash-4.2$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
```

This removed the oci.h file error but I was instead met with this error when installing via pip

```
distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: Oracle home (usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64) does not refer to an 10g, 11g or 12c installation.
```

Or this error when attempting to build from source I get an error about not having access to write to a location.

```
-bash-4.2$ python setup.py install
running install
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/test-
easy-install-15850.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

     /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

   https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

Given that I can confirm seeing what I believe are all the necessary files within $ORACLE_HOME/bin, $ORACLE_HOME/lib, and /usr/include/oracle/12.2/client64 how else would I verify that it is a valid installation of the Oracle Instant Client?

Or am I better off asking for write permissions at the site-packages location that the source code is attempting to build to?

Final notes

- I have tried to build from the source code of both cx_Oracle-6.0.rc2 and cx_Oracle-5.3 and I get the same errors about `Oracle home (usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64) does not refer to an 10g, 11g or 12c installation.`
- pip was installed locally just for the user I am sudo'd to and I run it via `.local/bin/pip install cx_Oracle` or whatever the package name is
- The current box is RHEL 7.1 but I had done it on a RHEL 4 and 5 box as part of development and then windows 10 for my local environment during testing.
- I can also verify that the oracle instant client is installed via rpms with `yum info oracle-instantclient12.2-basic` and `yum info oracle-instantclient12.2-devel` where both show installed

Overall, a bit lost with this install of cx_Oracle as before I had root/admin access but this box I will not.

Comment: 1. Does Oracle not host pre-compiled cx_Oracle binaries for RHEL 7? Have you tried those? 2. python setup.py and pip will always require write-access to site-packages since they install there. Best practice on production machines to minimize needing root/admin is to make sure your code installs and runs inside a virtualenv and then admin only needs virtualenv installed (you create a virtualenv in a location writeable by you, like $HOME, then you can pip to your hearts content).

Comment: Is that a cut/paste error, or are you really missing the leading '/' from the library path and ORACLE_HOME?  You have `usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib` where it should be `/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib` for the library path, and should have `/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64` for ORACLE_HOME. The `[Errno 13] Permission denied` message you are getting is because you don't have root privileges, so yes, ask for write permissions.  Note that for cx_Oracle 6 with Instant Client you don't need (and shouldn't in general) set ORACLE_HOME